# Python- making a set from a text file

Tags: python, text, set

I have a text file. The guts of it look like this/ all of it looks like this (has been edited. This was also not what it initially looked like)

```
 (0, 16, 0)
 (0, 17, 0)
 (0, 18, 0)
 (0, 19, 0)
 (0, 20, 0)
 (0, 21, 0)
 (0, 22, 0)
 (0, 22, 1)
 (0, 22, 2)
 (0, 23, 0)
 (0, 23, 4)
 (0, 24, 0)
 (0, 25, 0)
 (0, 25, 1)
 (0, 26, 0)
 (0, 26, 3)
 (0, 26, 4)
 (0, 26, 5)
 (0, 26, 9)
 (0, 27, 0)
 (0, 27, 1)
```

Anyway, how do I put these values into a set on python 2?

My most recent attempt was

```
om_set = set(open('Rye Grass.txt').read()
```

EDIT: This is the code I used to get my text file.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

```
om=cv2.imread('spectrum1.png')
om=om.reshape(1,-1,3)
om_list=om.tolist()
om_tuple={tuple(item) for item in om_list[0]}
om_set=set(om_tuple)

im=cv2.imread('1.jpg')        
im=cv2.resize(im,(100,100))         
im= im.reshape(1,-1,3)
im_list=im.tolist()
im_tuple={tuple(item) for item in im_list[0]}
ColourCount= om_set & set(im_tuple)
with open('Weedlist', 'a') as outputfile:
    output = ', '.join([str(tup) for tup in sorted(ColourCount)])
    outputfile.write(output)
print 'done'

im=cv2.imread('2.jpg')        
im=cv2.resize(im,(100,100))         
im= im.reshape(1,-1,3)
im_list=im.tolist()
im_tuple={tuple(item) for item in im_list[0]}
ColourCount= om_set & set(im_tuple)
with open('Weedlist', 'a') as outputfile:
    output = ', '.join([str(tup) for tup in sorted(ColourCount)])
    outputfile.write(output)
print 'done'
```

Comment: My most recent attempt was
    om_set =  set(open('Rye Grass.txt').read()

Comment: You need to parse the contents of the file - `file.read()` just reads everything into a long string, and if you call `set()` on that, you just get a set of all the characters. In order to parse it, the precise structure must be known (not just "the guts of it"). Is it always triplets of integer numbers, separated by commas?

Comment: It is triplets of integer numbers separated by commas always. It's pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimPietzcker suggested and trusting the file to only have these fixed representations of integers in comma separated triplets, surrounded by parentheses, a simple parser in one go (OP's question also had a greed "read" of file into memors):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function


infile = 'pixel_int_tuple_reps.txt'
split_pits = None
with open(infile, 'rt') as f_i:
    split_pits = [z.strip(' ()') for z in f_i.read().strip().split('),')]
if split_pits:
    on_set = set(tuple(int(z.strip())
                 for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)

    print(on_set)
```

tramsforms:

```
(0, 19, 0), (0, 20, 0), (0, 21, 1), (0, 22, 0), (0, 24, 3), (0, 27, 0), (0, 29, 2), (0, 35, 2), (0, 36, 1)
```

into:

```
set([(0, 27, 0), (0, 36, 1), (0, 21, 1), (0, 22, 0), (0, 24, 3), (0, 19, 0), (0, 35, 2), (0, 29, 2), (0, 20, 0)])
```

The small snippet:

1. splits the pixel integer triplets into substrings of `0, 19, 0` cleansing a bit the stray parens and spaces away (also taking care of the closing parentheses at the end.
2. if that "worked" - further feeds the rgb split with integer conversion tuples into a set.

I would really think twice, before using eval/exec on that kind of deserialization task.

**Update** as suggested by comments from OP (please update the question!):

1. The file at the OP's site seems to be too big to print (keep in memory)?
2. It is **not** written, as the advertised in question ...

... so until we have further info from OP:

For a theoretical clean 3-int-tuple dump file this answer works (if not too big to load at once and map into a set).

For the concrete task, I may update the answer if sufficient new info has been added to the question ;-)

One way, if the triple "lines" are concat from previous stages with or without a newline separating, but alwayss missing the comma, to change the file reading part either:

1. into a line based reader (when newlines separate) and pull the set generation into the loop always making a union of the new harvested set with the existing (accumulating one) like `s = s | fresh`  that is tackling them in "isolation"

or if these "chunks" are added like so `(0, 1, 230)(13, ...` that is `)(` "hitting hard":

2. modify the existing code inside reader and instead of: `f_i.read().strip().split('),')` write `f_i.read().replace(')('), (', ').strip().split('),')` ... that is "fixing" the `)(`part into a `), (`part to be able to continue as if it would be a homogene "structure".

**Update** now parsing the version 2 of the dataset (updated question):

File `pixel_int_tuple_reps_v2.txt`now has:

```
 (0, 16, 0)
 (0, 17, 0)
 (0, 18, 0)
 (0, 19, 0)
 (0, 20, 0)
 (0, 21, 0)
 (0, 22, 0)
 (0, 22, 1)
 (0, 22, 2)
 (0, 23, 0)
 (0, 23, 4)
 (0, 24, 0)
 (0, 25, 0)
 (0, 25, 1)
 (0, 26, 0)
 (0, 26, 3)
 (0, 26, 4)
 (0, 26, 5)
 (0, 26, 9)
 (0, 27, 0)
 (0, 27, 1)
```

The code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function


infile = 'pixel_int_tuple_reps_v2.txt'
on_set = set()
with open(infile, 'rt') as f_i:
    for line in f_i.readlines():
        rgb_line = line.strip().lstrip('(').rstrip(')')
        try:
            rgb = set([tuple(int(z.strip()) for z in rgb_line.split(', '))])
            on_set = on_set.union(rgb)
        except:
            print("Ignored:" + rgb_line)
            pass
print(len(on_set))
for rgb in sorted(on_set):
    print(rgb)
```

Now parses this file and first dumps the length of the set and (as is the elements in sorted order):

```
21
(0, 16, 0)
(0, 17, 0)
(0, 18, 0)
(0, 19, 0)
(0, 20, 0)
(0, 21, 0)
(0, 22, 0)
(0, 22, 1)
(0, 22, 2)
(0, 23, 0)
(0, 23, 4)
(0, 24, 0)
(0, 25, 0)
(0, 25, 1)
(0, 26, 0)
(0, 26, 3)
(0, 26, 4)
(0, 26, 5)
(0, 26, 9)
(0, 27, 0)
(0, 27, 1)
```

HTH. Note that there are no duplicates in the provided sample input. Doubling the last data line I still rceived 21 unique elements as output, so I guess now it works as designed ;-)

Comment: This is a pretty big set file... I'm not gonna be able to print it... what if I just said "len(on_set" instead to test it?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 14, in <module>
    for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '230)(1'

Comment: So it seems, the content of the text file with integer pixel triplets is not as consistently written as suggested ;-) ... and of course this new info, saying it is a big file (compared to memory or printing), you can always reduce the extracte info, by applying len() on the set. That depends on what you want to do with the disjoint RGB triplets stored in the set?

Comment: Well, I got the data from breaking down several pictures pixels into sets, then intersecting them to get all the similar pixel values and appended them to the text file, so probably an issue where it's joined. I'll add the program I used to get the data to the list

I want them stored in a set so I can then then use it to intersect with another set I get from taking a photo. It's basically a program that detects certain colours of green.

Comment: If the file (the triplets) is not too big, it would be great to have it to do some small parser cosmetics in above snippet, and it will also work for your real world problem ... otherwise it would be good to guess (and drill down on your side) at the hopefully single defect that tricks our parser. My guess is a newline instead of a top level separating comma, that will become stripped away and you have what you displayed in the comment above. BUt why guess, when we can simply test ... please provide, thanks  ;-)

Comment: Ok, I searched through the text, and now it all definitely looks like what I have posted above. Still getting an issue however.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 14, in <module>
    for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    for z in tup.split(', ')) for tup in split_pits)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0)\n (0'

Comment: I left her running for like, 10 minutes but it didn't seem to do anything?

Comment: Well, it seems to parse without errors ... Hoe many lines? I do not lnow, you might find that out. On a unix system one would use wc -l ie wordcount lines ...

Comment: It should be ok. When I made the file smaller it worked perfectly, thanks. What I've done is using this code I'm going to rewrite the data (as I think there's a lot of duplication) into a new set which I'll then launch into my other program. Thanks heap :)

Comment: On my machine  that naive reader / parser takes approx 10 seconds to parse a file constructed by repeatedly concatenating the input file  above (with an added duplicate line) adding in total to 2.2 * 10^6 lines ... Thanks for the feedback and happy hacking. You may always accept an answer, if it helps you sufficiently ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Only need small modification.You can try this.

```
om_set = set(eval(open('abc.txt').read()))
```

**Result**

```
{(0, 19, 0),
 (0, 20, 0),
 (0, 21, 1),
 (0, 22, 0),
 (0, 24, 3),
 (0, 27, 0),
 (0, 29, 2),
 (0, 35, 2)}
```

**Edit**
Here is the working of code in in `IPython` prompt.

```
In [1]: file_ = open('abc.txt')
In [2]: text_read = file_.read()
In [3]: print eval(text_read)
((0, 19, 0), (0, 20, 0), (0, 21, 1), (0, 22, 0), (0, 24, 3), (0, 27, 0), (0, 29, 2), (0, 35, 2), (0, 36, 1))
In [4]: type(eval(text_read))
Out[1]: tuple
In [5]: print set(eval(text_read))
set([(0, 27, 0), (0, 36, 1), (0, 21, 1), (0, 22, 0), (0, 24, 3), (0, 19, 0), (0, 35, 2), (0, 29, 2), (0, 20, 0)])
```

Comment: I'm getting an IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: but the file definitely exists

Comment: Dw. It started to listen. Now it says that tuple object is not callable?

Comment: @DaveyBoy You should probably split your solution into several lines of code (read file, eval, set).  Then you can more easily see problem, and also print intermediate results.  But, copy and paste the Complete traceback to your question when it fails

Comment: @DaveyBoy You have to replace the `abc.txt` with your filename.

Comment: I did Rahul. Also Joel, the issue seems to be with the line, but the module doesn't seem to like it? I'm using open cv2.

Comment: @DaveyBoy Please check and the expanding of my code. An tell me that which line you have problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Weed Hunter.py", line 19, in <module>
    type(eval(text_read))
  File "<string>", line 2
    (0, 17, 0)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @DaveyBoy Skip that line. what about the rest ?

Comment: Other than that she seems to be all good mate? What does this mean?

Comment: Also I can't print that stuff because it's a very big file- will crash my computer before it prints.

Comment: @DaveyBoy I mean are you able to translate to `set` with my code ?